# Calculating number of pixels of dominant class in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, zonal-statistics, pixel

I have a land use classification raster file and a grided (5 km² grids) shapefile of my study region. I want to compute a landscape complexity index (LC) which can be computed by: LC = number of classes / number of pixels of dominant class.

I could compute the number of classes per grid with zonal statistics, but I am struggling with the calculation of the number of pixels of the dominant class  per grid. How can that be accomplished?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [Zonal histogram](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/rasteranalysis.html#zonal-histogram) tool:

Appends fields representing counts of each unique value from a raster layer contained within polygon features.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that is a good idea. However, I have 50000 grids in my vector layer. How can I now extract the highest histogram value for each row?

Comment: Field calculator. https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/323419/finding-minimum-value-of-different-columns-using-qgis